# Float div inside another div when scrolling

Tags: html, css

I need to make a div float inside another div and move on scrolling, but I need the floating div to not pop out of a container div

I need the floating div to stay inside the container div

Any idea how to do this?

```css
body {
  height: 800px;
}

#main-container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: black;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

#secondary-container {
  width: 90px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: red;
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="main-container">
    <div id="secondary-container"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: position sticky instead

Comment: @TemaniAfif the div doesn't move when scrolling the page

Comment: you need to specify a top value (or bottom), check the duplicat to understand how sticky works